# What is the "Default Timeout" value in SQLite connection string used for?

Tags: sqlite, c#

I have looked at the SQLite documentation and I can't find anything clear about the value "*Default Timeout*".

Looking at other websites, it seems to refer to some sort of "*Connection timeout*", while other sites indicate that it is more of a "*Command timeout*"

Some quick tests don't seem to indicate that it has anything to do with Commands.

Can anybody confirm/reference what the purpose of that value in the connection string is for?

**Edit** this is using the [official SQLite .NET library](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki)

Comment: SQLite itself does not have a connection string. Are you talking about some .NET driver? Which one?

Comment: Sorry, it is the "Official" .NET package, http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found this out by looking at the source code: The timeout value of a command is [initialized](https://github.com/haf/System.Data.SQLite/blob/8d2e5027723654e97d2ad208b9a076da496eee79/System.Data.SQLite/SQLiteCommand.cs#L149) to `DefaultTimeout` and [passed](https://github.com/haf/System.Data.SQLite/blob/8d2e5027723654e97d2ad208b9a076da496eee79/System.Data.SQLite/SQLite3.cs#L800) to the internal [SQLite3.Prepare](https://github.com/haf/System.Data.SQLite/blob/8d2e5027723654e97d2ad208b9a076da496eee79/System.Data.SQLite/SQLite3.cs#L891) function.

This is used to control a loop that automatically retries statements that fail with a Locked or Busy error.  When the timeout has expired (as measured by `Environment.TickCount`), then an exception is thrown with whatever the most recent error code was.  Otherwise, it sleeps for a random amount of time (between 1 and 150 ms) and tries again.